# How to make AirPlay button to appear?

Tags: airplay, mdns, dns-sd

Currently I'm trying to make some kind of airplay server, but failed. The problem is that the airplay button doesn't appears on my ios device. I've followed [this link](http://redragger.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/using-java-to-mimic-an-airplay-server/), and I'm stuck at part where I need to register the airplay service. I'm using
`dns-sd -R MyAirplayService _airplay._tcp local 22555` command, service shows as registrated, but no button for me. Tried to change port to 7000 or 7100, but same result. Can you show me, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to register a corresponding `_raop._tcp` service.

By corresponding, I mean the mac addresses (aka device ids) need to match.

For more details on what the announcements should look like, see http://nto.github.io/AirPlay.html

It used to be that only registering the `_airplay._tcp` was enough, but that has since changed...